# How to install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox and MozRepl::RemoteObject?

Tags: perl, cpan

I want to use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox. Trying to install it via cpan

```
one dependency not OK (MozRepl::RemoteObject); additionally test harness failed
```

Trying to install MozRepl::RemoteObject will not be installed cos of failed tests....

Of course I have installed MozRepl plugin in FF.

Answer (score 0):

Same on my site. When I saw they were just some, but not all fails from the make tests.
I found, that this may happen:
http://www.techiecorner.com/1839/cpan-error-make-test-had-returned-bad-status-wont-install-without-force/
As it were most but definitely not all tests failed I just used a sudo cpan force install MozRepl.
Using MozRepl quite much during the last weeks and I think all sub-modles like plugins, client and log I tried work as they should.